# How do I know that I am mining?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, bug, balances, ethminer

Is that everything is ok with this result?

When will I receive my first coin? And why can't I see my balance, it shows (it started about 8 hours from first) When I type `eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase)` in the `geth attach` it prints `←[31m0←[0m`

Is it ok? What does that mean?

in `geth --rpc`:

```
I0618 21:15:35.492554 core/blockchain.go:964] imported 1 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 21 txs in 414.5035ms. #1727499 [53777429 / 53777429]
I0618 21:15:47.059936 core/blockchain.go:964] imported 1 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 4 txs in 775.0133ms. #1727500 [3fcc2930 / 3fcc2930]
I0618 22:14:07.945653 miner/miner.go:119] Starting mining operation (CPU=0 TOT=1)
I0618 22:14:08.413245 miner/worker.go:555] commit new work on block 1727501 with 7 txs & 0 uncles. Took 467.592ms
```

and in `ethminer`:

```
miner 22:45:02|main Mining on PoWhash #e18a69e1ΓÇª : 26317606 H/s = 13369344 hashes / 0.508 s
miner 22:45:03|main Mining on PoWhash #e18a69e1ΓÇª : 26315613 H/s = 13631488 hashes / 0.518 s
miner 22:45:03|main Mining on PoWhash #e18a69e1ΓÇª : 25959891 H/s = 13369344 hashes / 0.515 s
miner 22:45:04|main Mining on PoWhash #e18a69e1ΓÇª : 26315613 H/s = 13631488 hashes / 0.518 s
miner 22:45:04|main Mining on PoWhash #e18a69e1ΓÇª : 26473948 H/s = 13369344 hashes / 0.505 s
miner 22:45:05|main Mining on PoWhash #e18a69e1ΓÇª : 25809544 H/s = 13369344 hashes / 0.518 s
miner 22:45:05|main Mining on PoWhash #e18a69e1ΓÇª : 26264909 H/s = 13631488 hashes / 0.519 s
miner 22:45:06|main Mining on PoWhash #e18a69e1ΓÇª : 26526476 H/s = 13369344 hashes / 0.504 s
miner 22:45:06|main Mining on PoWhash #e18a69e1ΓÇª : 25809544 H/s = 13369344 hashes / 0.518 s
miner 22:45:07|main Mining on PoWhash #e18a69e1ΓÇª : 25959891 H/s = 13369344 hashes / 0.515 s
miner 22:45:08|main Mining on PoWhash #e18a69e1ΓÇª : 26315613 H/s = 13631488 hashes / 0.518 s
miner 22:45:08|main Mining on PoWhash #e18a69e1ΓÇª : 26417612 H/s = 13631488 hashes / 0.516 s
miner 22:45:09|main Mining on PoWhash #e18a69e1ΓÇª : 26058051 H/s = 13107200 hashes / 0.503 s
miner 22:45:09|main Mining on PoWhash #e18a69e1ΓÇª : 25909581 H/s = 13369344 hashes / 0.516 s
miner 22:45:10|main Mining on PoWhash #e18a69e1ΓÇª : 26214400 H/s = 13631488 hashes / 0.52 s
miner 22:45:11|main Mining on PoWhash #e18a69e1ΓÇª : 26178538 H/s = 38273024 hashes / 1.462 s
miner 22:47:09|main Got work package:
miner 22:47:09|main Header-hash: 006d90f968a348a4a960ccc68db599332139ba2049a7980c2c21ec23d1317d2d
miner 22:47:09|main Seedhash: a1cf12393876a9e30788eb582aeea764ad71d6b2419f2c6b35706ec60b49c85c
miner 22:47:09|main Target: 000000000006884aa8f81f060331f21097467838b975026daf831976e216f89c
i 22:47:09|gpuminer0 workLoop 1 #a1cf1239ΓÇª #a1cf1239ΓÇª
miner 22:47:09|main Mining on PoWhash #006d90f9ΓÇª : 25165824
```

Comment: This seems to be a bug with coloured output in geth.

Comment: Possibly this, or similar: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2668

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have an issue with coloured output in your geth client. The `←[31m0←[0m` are colour codes which were not interpreted by your terminal. However, if you ignore everything between `←` and `m` you will see there is a `0` in the middle of that snippet, which tells you your balance is 0.

To find out when you will recieve ether, please consult [a mining calculator](https://badmofo.github.io/ethereum-mining-calculator/) and enter your hashrate. For 26MH/s it will take you around 1 month to find a block. So you better mine at some pool.

The ethminer output looks good.